# Winum can not locate elements on windows 10

Tags: winium

I am newbie using Winium and installed a sample test - steps are only to open Notepad and click on the File button/menu item. The launching of the application (Notepad) works but it seems it can not locate the button. I have tried to locate using both name and id attributes without any luck. I am running on Windows 10 so my guess is it has something to do with this..Any tips or workarounds highly appriciated - i will pase my simple code below

Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    DesktopOptions option = new DesktopOptions();
    option.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");

    WiniumDriver driver = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.name("File"));

    el.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting a reference to the window first, and then looking within that for an element called 'File'.

This works for me.

```
        var window = driver.FindElementByClassName("Notepad");

        var fileMenuHeader = window.FindElement(By.Name("File"));
        fileMenuHeader.Click();
```

I'm not sure how you get the next level of menus though - it doesn't appear to be part of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the menu-bar first with its ID.
Then with that element try catching the menu options like file, edit,etc. 
Below code works fine on Windows 10.

```
var menubar = Driver.FindElementById("MenuBar");
            var editMenu = menubar.FindElement(By.Name("Edit"));
            var FileMenu = menubar.FindElement(By.Name("File");
            editMenu.Click();
```